# CMake error when trying to include Crow to C++ Qt Widget project

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, visual-studio-2022

## Goal

Trying to add [Crow](https://crowcpp.org/master/) as dependency into my MVS Project, while using CMake building into Gitlab's pipeline.

## Scenario

### CI

I'm a Jr. Dev trying to implement a new API into a project, but quite new with CMake configuration.

All commits goes validated by a Gitlabs cmake build routine, but it is failing after adding Crow reference.

### Project

On first hand, I cannot show all the codes beacause company privacy don't allows me to do it.

I'm trying to add Crow as a web API into a Qt C++ Project currently made with Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 (Qt's qmake: msvc2017_64) into development setup.

The Solution has different .lib and .exe projects in it, but the Crow is gonna be added to an executable project called `MainProject.vcxproj` for privacy purposes.

For CMake configuration there is two CMakeLists.txt, one inside solution's root folder and other inside MainProject's folder.

For Crow usage, I followed this [tutorial](https://crowcpp.org/master/getting_started/setup/windows/#using-a-package-manager) using vcpkg manager. Simple: `vcpkg install crow`

Created `VCPKG_DIR`system's variable referencing to: `D:\devtools\vcpkg`

Then I added into `MainProject` configurations:

- C/C++ > General > Additional Inclide Directories: `$(VCPKG_DIR)\installed\x64-windows\include`
- Linker > General > Additional Library Directories: `$(VCPKG_DIR)\installed\x64-windows\lib`

Afther this, I added into the main.cpp this [simple app](https://crowcpp.org/master/getting_started/your_first_application/#putting-it-all-together) example and it runs blocking my application. (Issue for another time)

## CMake Issue

After configuring the project I staterd with this file located into ...`/SolutionDir>:/CMakeLists.txt`:

I had several issues while adding the crow reference, as recommended by vcpkg:

```bash
find_package(Crow CONFIG REQUIRED)
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${VCPKG_DIR}/installed/x64-windows/share/crow")

#Crow framework
set(CROW_DIR "$ENV{VCPKG_DIR}")
set(CROW_INCLUDE_DIR "${CROW_DIR}/installed/x64-windows/include/crow")
```

Then I was sure that only adding a few lines to this was gonna work: ...`/SolutionDir/MainProjectDir/CMakeLists.txt'

```bash
target_link_libraries(AutazaPaintInspection
    PUBLIC Crow::Crow
    ...

target_include_directories(AutazaPaintInspection PUBLIC
    "${CROW_INCLUDE_DIR}"
    ...
```

## Result

Gitlab returns this projects dependency error that is not correlated with Crow at all:

<gitlab_runner_path>\main.cpp(29,10): fatal  error C1083: Não é possível abrir arquivo incluir: 'mvIMPACT_CPP/mvIMPACT_acquire.h': No such file or directory [<path_to_main_project>\MainProject.vcxproj]

"Não é possível abrir arquivo incluir" translates to: Unable to open include file

That's it. Sorry for any mistakes, not native.

Comment: Does the project have two build systems that you should maintain? If not (i.e. you are generating vcxproj from CMakeLists.txt), then you should only change `CMakeLists.txt`. Does the project already integrates with vcpkg?

Comment: As I reckon vcxproj on desktop developer environment gets generated by Qt Vs tools, am I right? 
But We have a computer dedicated to cmake builds. So these CMakeLists configurations that I described, are all specific coded aiming this dedicated separated environment that contains a copy of our repo, but generates build output with CMake.

And no, I didn't know that vcpkg should be integrated with vcpkg. What does that mean?

Comment: Closing the issue. Changed from Crow to Drogon framework.